# How to count number of lines with only 1 character?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

Im trying to just print counted number of lines which have only 1 character.

I have a file with 200k lines some of the lines have only one character (any type of character)

Since I have no experience I have googled a lot and **scraped** documentation and come up with this mixed solution from different sources:

```
awk -F^\w$ '{print NF-1}' myfile.log
```

I was expecting that will filter lines with single char, and it seems work

```
^\w$
```

However Im not getting number of the lines containing a single character. Instead something like this: [image]

Comment: Define what is a character. Today, [UTF-8 is used everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/). So is a line with just `€` or `°` or `Ê` a line with a single character? It has more than one byte before the newline.

Comment: Yes, exactly a line with any character is count as single character line in my case

Comment: And what about the `NUL` character? How many one character lines does `/bin/ls` have? It is some [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) executable! Use also [od(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html)

Comment: `seq 20 | grep -c '^.$'`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Provided that `LANG` is set properly, multibyte characters pose no problem. For instance, `echo あ|grep  -c '^.$'` prints **1** for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a non-awk solution is OK:

```
grep -c '^.$'
```

Comment: how we can adapt this solution for "Lines ending with single char? eg: sometext here and im the single char =

Comment: @deuq. Um... all lines with at least one char end in a single char. Do you want the last character to be separated by something (e.g. spaces) just rephrase the requirement as *"lines whose 2nd last char is a space"*; from there `grep -c ' .$'` should be obvious. However, please don't change you question midway -- instead, ask a new one.

Comment: Thomas,  @Socowi I appreciate your help, however, I feel ashamed for myself now I will spend more time on documentation. This was solution for this task.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
awk '/^.$/{++c}END{print c}' file
```

The variable `c` is incremented for every line containing only 1 character (any character).
When the parsing of the file is finished, the variable is printed.

Answer (score 2):

In awk, rules like your `{print NF-1}` are executed for *each* line. To print only one thing for the whole file you have to use `END { print ... }`. There you can print a counter which you increment each time you see a line with one character.

However, I'd use `grep` instead because it is easier to write and faster to execute:

```
grep -xc . yourFile
```